# Opentelemetry auto-instrumentation for Node js

Tags: node.js, observable, open-telemetry, opentracing, observability

I am using ESM in my node application, when I tried opentelemetry to auto instrument my app using [@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node) package I could not generate any tracing, is this normal behavior? is there a suggested way to auto-instrument with ESM? Or I am left with the option to manual instrument my app.

Answer (score 1):

The auto-instrumentation only works with libraries that are currently supported.

You can take a look at the [OpenTelemetry Registry](https://opentelemetry.io/ecosystem/registry/) to check all supported libraries.

You can also check the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/tree/main/plugins/node), in which you could raise a Feature Request to ask for the implementation of an auto instrumentation for ESM.

At the moment ESM is not supported by the auto instrumentation, and in order to get traces and metrics to your code, you will need to manually instrument your code.

This process is detailed in the [OpenTelemetry official documentation](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/instrumentation/).